# How to count number of categories in DataFrame object?

Tags: python, pandas

Let say we have a DataFrame object with number of boxes. Each box has a fruit inside 'Apple', 'Banana' or 'Peach'.

How to count how many boxes have 'Apple' or 'Bananas' or 'Peach' inside?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean something such as:

```
from collections import Counter
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['apple','apple','banana','peach', 'banana', 'apple']})

print Counter(df['a'])
>> Counter({'apple': 3, 'banana': 2, 'peach': 1})
```

You can also use `groupby`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['apple','apple','banana','peach', 'banana', 'apple']})

print df.groupby(['a']).size()
>> a
   apple     3
   banana    2
   peach     1
```

Comment: Yes, but may I make it little bit more complex. Let say we have vegetables as well like 'pumpkin', 'potato' mixed with fruits. And separate column that has type 'Fruit' or 'Vegetable'. Can I count number of fruits or vegetables separately? Like Fruit Peach - 3, Vegetable Pumpkin - 5, etc?